# Why am I getting brackets in between text when trying to print some text in the Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to print some text on the Tkinter canvas along with an image which is doing fine. But unfortunately, some curly braces are also being printed on the screen without using them anywhere in the print statement. I am fetching some part of the text from a dataframe and storing it in a variable before printing it on the screen.

My code is as follows:

```
best_batsmen = dataset.loc[dataset.loc[dataset['Innings']>=15,'Average'].idxmax(),'Names']
message = ("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",best_batsmen)
canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500
root = Toplevel()
root.geometry("700x600")
root.title("New Window")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("virat.jpeg"))
canvas.create_image(0, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)
canvas.image = img
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the above code it's printing `{The best Batsmen of the Tournament could possibly be:} {Virat Kohli}` instead of `The best Batsmen of the Tournament could possible be: Virat Kohli`. Those curly braces are looking quite odd. Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: You need for `message` to be a string rather than a tuple: `"The best..." + best_batsmen` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

It's either in a set or a dictionary in your dataset. Just convert it to a string before displaying:

```
string = ''.join(str(l) for l in list(name))
```

This will do the trick for any amount of elements in a set.

Answer (score 0):

This code sets `message` to a tuple:

```
message = ("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",best_batsmen)
```

This uses the tuple as the value of the `text` attribute *without converting it to a string*:

```
canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message)
```

This value gets passed down to the underlying tcl interepreter as a list (from Tcl's perspective). When tcl converts a list to a string, which it must do before adding it to the canvas, it adds curly braces in order to retain it's list-like properties.

The solution is simple: don't pass lists or tuples to tkinter functions. Explicitly convert them to a string first:

```
message = " ".join(message)
canvas.create_text(1, 10, anchor=W, text=message)
```